# Returning response REST API error messages with python

Tags: python, json, rest, httpresponse

I'm sending a simple REST API call in python:

```
import json
import requests
import time


url = 'https://server:9899/123456789/open.scan'
data = {'alpha':'one','beta':'two'}

print 'Sending open.scan command: ' + str(data)
try:
    response = requests.post(url, data=data, verify=false)
    print response.status_code
except:
   print "failed"
```

This all works correctly and triggers the API.  However, if the apikey I feed is bad I get back a 405 error (as expected?).

The issue I'm having is this:

When I issue this API call over a web browser as simply:

```
https://server:9899/api/wrongapikeyhere/open.sesame
```

The page returned to me actually states "Wrong API key used"

I'm trying to figure out how to get that returned string into my python code so that I can actually print out what the specific error is and not simply a 405.

Comment: `response.text`?

Comment: No, I've tried this.  I simply get  `<html><title>405: Method Not Allowed</title><body>405: Method Not Allowed</body></html>`  If I take the output of `response.url` and plug it into the browser I get the "wrong API key used", so my assumption is that should somehow be returned through the python code as well?

Comment: That is an other error.

Comment: Your code (presumably, you've hidden it of course) supplies an API key as POST data.  Replicating this through a browser session isn't as easy as just visiting the API endpoint's URL (where no post data is provided), so the error message you get when visiting the endpoint in your browser makes sense.  In other words, your *real* issue likely *isn't* that you're using an incorrect API key, but just what it says, that the method isn't allowed.

Comment: @jedwards - I'm not sure I understand you correctly, but I think you may be on to something in that "browser URL" != "post data from python code", but I don't know where the difference lies.  My `url` string in the code above works perfectly either from the code or placed directly in a browser.  If I change the `123456789` to an incorrect API code then the browser gives me "wrong API key used" but the python code gives me the "405: method not allowed."  In the end I am simply looking to provide more descriptive information back through the script if a wrong API code were to be used.

Comment: Are you actually POSTing data through your browser request? Or just pasting the URL into the address?

Comment: I am just pasting - which I realize is different than a post command.  Is it not common for an API to return detailed error information (like "wrong API key") through post reqeusts - or just status codes?  I assume there is a way for me to send the URL through python, but doing so would probably lose all the easy json data handling?